# Use basename in react-router on server side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I'm serving my site from `/clientpanel` directory on my server. So my url is `http://xxx.yy/clientpanel`. This is my client-side code:

```js
const history = useRouterHistory(createHistory)({
    basename: "/clientpanel"
});

render(
    <Router history={history} routes={routes}/>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

On client-side everything works just fine. All urls are relative to `/clientpanel`, but I have problem on how to get this work on server. This is my server-side code:

```js
const history = useRouterHistory(createMemoryHistory)({
    basename: "/clientpanel"
});

match({ routes, location: req.url, history}, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (renderProps) {
        const html = renderToString(
            <RouterContext {...renderProps}/>
        );

        res.send(renderFullPage(html))
    }
});
```

On first page load I need to omit `/clientpanel` in url to get this work, but then on client-side after clicking first `<Link>` `/clientpanel` is added to the begining. How to make it works consistent on both client and server side?

Comment: It seems like `createMemoryHistory` doesn't support `basename`. You can just remove the basename from `req.url` and it will work, but `Link`s will be still broken.

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it to work with the following code:

```js
const basename = '/foo'
const location = req.url.replace(basename, '')
// createMemoryHistory from the history package
const history = useRouterHistory(() => createMemoryHistory(location))({ basename })

match({ history, routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
```

**EDIT**

Even better:

```
const basename = '/foo'
const location = req.url.replace(basename, '')
// createMemoryHistory from the react-router package
const history = createMemoryHistory({ entries: [location], basename })

match({ history, routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the basename to match:

```
match({ routes, location: req.url, basename: "/clientpanel" }, ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

const history = createMemoryHistory({ entries: [location], basename })

This doesn't work because createMemoryHistory doesn't have parameter basename.. The link will be different between client side and server side

I got a solution in the server side by replacing createHref like this :

```
import { createPath } from 'history/PathUtils';
[...]
history.createHref = location => '/' + language + createPath(location);
```